# PHP Codeigniter Oracle out of memory

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, memory

I have a problem. When I loop through a bunch of sql selects based on year and month
and I get a hit in a table, the memory usage EXPLODES !!!!

I am running php 5.1, Oracle 10.1, Codeigniter 2.02 on a Centos box.

Here is some log output containing memory usage:

> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:26 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '01' mem set: 1788664
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:27 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 0
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:27 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '02' mem set: 1793128
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:28 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 0
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:28 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '03' mem set: 1793728
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:30 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 0
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:30 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '04' mem set: 1794328
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:32 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 0
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:32 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '05' mem set: 1794928
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:33 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 0
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:33 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '06' mem set: 1795528
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:35 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 0
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:35 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '07' mem set: 1796128
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:37 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 0
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:37 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '08' mem set: 1796728
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:38 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 0
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:38 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '09' mem set: 1797392
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:45 --> RESULT COUNT IS: 224162
>
> INFO  - 2011-12-09 16:10:45 --> LOOP : NF: 28  YEAR: 2010 MONTH: '10' mem set: 486504280

NF = number of fields

So if a row of data in the table is 1000 bytes total (it's actually a lot less)
, and I have 224162 records,
then 224162*1000 = 224 megs of memory. Let's throw in a little bit for overhead .

I should not get DOUBLE the amount of memory used !!!

I have my max memory set to 512M. But that is not the problem.
The problem is the expolosion in memory usage.

I am doing this with the results of the query:

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. It seems that the codeigniter database class
does weird things. I don't know exactly what. It looks like it is dragging the
full result set into memory.

My solution:

I managed to get things to work by throwing out all the codeigniter database class
code and re-programming the model in question with 
PHP OCI8 code. Memory never went above 1.6 megs.

Sigh...

Best regards,

Phil